# How to exclude percentiles from Spark's summary()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Spark's `summary()` function returns count, mean, stddev and 25/50/75% percentiles.

Is it possible to compute only count, mean and stddev?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're speaking about Datasets' summary() function.

In which case, this should work:

```
yourDataset.summary( "count", "min", "stddev" ).show()
```

Based on https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset